# Where to load data from server for faster results?

Tags: javascript

When you open the page with :

```
www.domain.com/1/?name=lili
```

I extract the `name`, get data *from server* and reload current UI(`html`) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     let path = window.location.href ;
     let name = path.split('=')[1];

     getData(name);

});
```

The problem is that on the first moment there is actually a 1-2 seconds before loading where you see the skeleton.
***While creating a loader is easy***, I wonder if there is a faster way to do so, like doing it on the `head` .

The problem is that I may call DOM elements before document is ready.

Where do I read parameters from server to make it faster ?

Comment: set the loader on by default

Comment: Can't you handle this on the server side and respond with ready UI to the browser? Why do you want to handle query params on the client side and make additional requests to the server anyway?